# How do I pass a parameter to a JSP via a cross-context JSTL import?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I've come across a few other questions that describe a similar, but not identical situation, to mine. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351773/problem-with-jspparam-cparam-in-a-portlet), for instance, shows pretty much the same problem, except that I'm not using portlets - I'm just using boring ol' JSP+JSTL+EL+etc.

I have two application contexts, and I'd like to import a JSP from one to the other. I know how do that:

```
<c:import context="/" url="/WEB-INF/jsp/foo.jsp"/>
```

However, I also want to pass a parameter to the imported `foo.jsp`. But this code:

```
<c:import context="/" url="/WEB-INF/jsp/foo.jsp">
    <c:param name="someAttr" value="someValue"/>
</c:import>
```

does not seem to properly send the parameter to `foo.jsp`; if `foo.jsp` is something like*

```
<% System.out.println("foo.jsp sees that someAttr is: "
                      + pageContext.findAttribute("someAttr")); %>
```

then this gets printed out:

```
foo.jsp sees that someAttr is: null
```

whereas I want to see this:

```
foo.jsp sees that someAttr is: someValue
```

so, obviously, `someAttr` can't be found in `foo.jsp`.

**How do I fix this?**

---

*(yes, I know, `scriplets==bad`, this is just for debugging this one problem)

Comment: How are you making sure that your `foo.jsp`, is actually imported?

Comment: @Adeel: I'm not sure I see what you're getting at. When I request a page that imports `foo.jsp`, I see the `println` show up in my console, and I see an attempt at processing the other content of `foo.jsp`, except that it depends on `${someAttr}`. Sorry, it's late for me - does that answer it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting it as a request parameter, so you should also be getting it as request parameter.

Since you seem to dislike scriptlets as well, here's an EL solution:

```
${param.someAttr}
```

Note that `<c:import>` doesn't add any extra advantages above `<jsp:include>` in this particular case. It's useful whenever you want to import files from a different context or an entirely different domain, but this doesn't seem to be the case now. The following should also just have worked:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/foo.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="someAttr" value="someValue" />
</jsp:include>
```

This way the included page has access to the same `PageContext` *and* `HttpServletRequest` as the main JSP. This may end up to be more useful.

Comment: I am actually trying to import JSPs from a different context. I'll try retrieving it with your `${param.someAttr}` suggestion - if that works, is there any way to access `someAttr` as if it were an attribute of the page/request/etc (e.g. like `${someAttr}`)?

Comment: No, it concerns a different request. Session is best what you can get if the contexts share the same session (configureable in server config). Regardless, I'd prefer request parameters to avoid unforeseen clashes among different requests in the same session.