# How to identify the page calling <c:import> when importing JSP content

Tags: jsp, static-import

On a web application, I used the `<c:import>` tag from the JSTL core library in order to clean up my JSPs a bit and remove as much code redundancy as was possible.

I have a section which I wrapped in another file that way in order to prepare for display in different JSPs (it is already externalized, but there is only one use as of yet). Basically, it is a single `<div>` element, like this (variable names are in French), holding a table of application wide data. Right now, the data is read-only (through this display at least)

```
<div id="tableauTrajets">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${empty applicationScope.trajets}">
            <p class="erreur">Vous n'avez aucun train enregistré dans l'application pour le moment</p>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <div class="liste">
                <h1>Trains enregistrés</h1>
                <table border="1" class="sortable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Numéro de Train</th>
                        <th>Heure Départ</th>
                        <th>Gare Départ</th>
                        <th>Heure d'Arrivée</th>
                        <th>Gare Destination</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach items="${applicationScope.trajets}" var="mapTrajets" varStatus="boucle">
                        <tr>
                            <td><c:out value="${mapTrajets.value.numeroTrain}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${mapTrajets.value.heureDepart}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${mapTrajets.value.gareDepart}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${mapTrajets.value.heureArrivee}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${mapTrajets.value.gareArrivee}" /></td>
                            <td class="action">
                                <a href="
                                    <c:url value ="/reutiliserTrajet">
                                    <c:param name="identificateurTrajet" value="${mapTrajets.key}"/>
                                    </c:url>
                                    ">
                                    <img
                                        src="<c:url value="/inc/icons/24/reutiliser.png"/>"
                                        alt="Reutiliser"
                                        title="Réutiliser le trajet"
                                        class="iconeMenuTableau"
                                    />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
            </div>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</div>
```

I want to add this `<div>` in another page, an administration pannel designed to provide write access to app administrators only, but slightly modified, with some more `<th>` and `<td>` elements on each row to provide links to the editing features (basically, delete and update data displayed on this table).

**So my question is the following:**
Is there a way to identify the JSP page which is calling `<c:import>` in the JSP being called, in order to make a selective display using `<c:if>` or `<c:choose>` and which is it ? Google's most relevant response on JSP include identify page [caller/calling] was a 12y/o thread on Java Ranch with no response.

Alternatively, if I created a pageScope or requestScope variable in the caller page, could I use this in the imported page ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass a parameter to a JSP via a cross-context JSTL import?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920546/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-jsp-via-a-cross-context-jstl-import)

Comment: So I should pass a parameter when calling ?

Comment: As noted in the possible duplicate Q/A, use `<c:import ...> <c:param name="foo" value="foo"/> </c:import>` and it will be passed as a request parameter, you could access to this variable in the imported JSP as `${param.foo}`.